# Instantiating a struct parameterized by a trait

Tags: rust

I'm building a webapp in Rust and trying to implement basic Rails-style database migrations for managing my database. In my code, `Migration` is a trait with `up` and `down` methods to apply and roll back the migration. Each individual database migration is a struct that implements the Migration trait. To keep track of database migrations in the correct order, I built a `MigrationIndex` class.

```
struct MigrationIndex<T> {
    migrations: Vec<Box<T>>
}
impl <T: Migration> MigrationIndex<T> {
    // methods for managing the migrations...
}

impl <T: Migration> Default for MigrationIndex<T> {
    pub fn default() -> MigrationIndex<T> {
        MigrationIndex {
            migrations: vec![]
        }
    }
}
```

So I go to use my class:

```
let migrations: MigrationIndex = Default::default();
```

But the compiler errors on this line with `wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0`. So I tried to add the missing trait parameter:

```
let migrations: MigrationIndex<Migration> = Default::default();
```

But on that line the compiler interprets Migration as a type, not a trait, and again fails to compile. At a guess I tried:

```
let migrations: MigrationIndex<T: Migration> = Default::default();
```

but that ends up being a syntax error. Now I'm stumped. If a type is parameterized by a trait, how do I specify that trait when I instantiate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a generic, the generic argument needs to be of a single concrete type. This would cause all objects in the migrations `Vec` to be of the same type. From your description it does not sound like that's what you want. You want a `Vec` of different types that implement the same trait. This does not require generics:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct MigrationIndex {
    migrations: Vec<Box<Migration>>
}
impl MigrationIndex {
    // methods for managing the migrations...
}
```

I also took the liberty of replacing your manual `Default` impl with the equivalent automatically generated one through the `derive` attribute.

In fact, in your previous implementation, the `Box` was entirely unnecessary. If you have a concrete type, you can create a `Vec` of elements of that type directly. Only when you want to put in different types implementing the same trait do you need the `Box`, because these types might have different sizes.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a value for a generic type parameter, it has to be a concrete type, not a trait:

```
trait Migration {}

struct Foo;
impl Migration for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let migrations: MigrationIndex<Foo> = Default::default();
}
```